# Better/Right way to write a complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

This is my table.

```
SELECT * FROM [Message]
```

[image: Message Table Data]

Now what I want is, I want the list of only last message which User with **Id: 101** has sent or received from any other user. The query which I wrote for it is below

```
SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 [Message_id]
 FROM [Message]
 WHERE
 ([Sender_id] = REC.[Sender_id] AND [Receiver_id] = REC.[Receiver_id])
 OR
 ([Sender_id] = REC.[Receiver_id] AND [Receiver_id] = REC.[Sender_id])
 ORDER BY 1 DESC) AS [Message Id],
REC.[Sender_id] AS [Sender Id],
REC.[Receiver_id] AS [Receiver Id],
(SELECT TOP 1 [Message]
 FROM [Message]
 WHERE
 ([Sender_id] = REC.[Sender_id] AND [Receiver_id] = REC.[Receiver_id])
 OR
 ([Sender_id] = REC.[Receiver_id] AND [Receiver_id] = REC.[Sender_id])
 ORDER BY 1 DESC) AS [Message]
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT [Sender_id], [Receiver_id]
 FROM [Message]
 WHERE [Sender_id] = '101') REC
```

And I am getting the following result which seems fine.

[image: Query Results]

I'm new to DB queries and it seems that my query is very inefficient and long. Can anyone please suggest a better way to write this query? Also, using **JOINS** if that might be a better possible way to write this query.

**Note:** Please consider Message_id to be just a unique number and not a ordered identity column which in actual scenario may be any generated unique alphanumeric code.

Thanks.

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server.  Why is the question tagged SQLite?

Comment: Why are you tagging `SQL Server` code with `sqlite`?

Comment: SQLite is tagged because I'd prefer the suggestions in either SQL Server or SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
WITH Priorities AS (
   SELECT
      Priority = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY X.Party2 ORDER BY Message_id DESC),
      M.*
   FROM
      dbo.Message M
      OUTER APPLY (VALUES
         (M.Sender_id, M.Receiver_Id),
         (M.Receiver_id, M.Sender_Id)
      ) X (Party1, Party2)
   WHERE
      Party1 = '101'
)
SELECT *
FROM Priorities
WHERE Priority = 1     
;
```

## [See this working in a Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/300a3/2)

Explanation:

The real problem is that you don't care whether the selected person is the sender or the receiver. This leads to complication dealing with pulling the value from one column or the other, such as can be solved in typical fashion with a `CASE` statement.

However, I'm always a fan of solving things like this relationally instead of procedurally, so I simplified the problem by (basically) doubling up the data. For each source row in the table, we're generating two rows, one where the sender comes first, and one where the receiver comes first. We don't care which one is the sender or receiver, and we can just say that we're looking for `Party1` to be id `101`, and then want to find, for each `Party2` that he exchanged a message with (and whether he was sender or receiver is irrelevant), the most recent one.

`OUTER APPLY` is just a trick for us to avoid doing more CTEs or nested queries (another way to write it). It's like a `LEFT JOIN`, but lets one use outer references (it refers to columns in table `M`).

For what it's worth, `Message_id` doesn't seem like a reliable way to choose the latest message. You should have a date column and order by that instead! (Just add a `datetime` or `datetime2` column to your table, and change the `ORDER BY` to use it. You never know if messages could be inserted to the table out of order from when they actually occurred--them being out of order should in fact be expected. What if you have to back-insert lost messages? Identity columns are not a good way to guarantee insertion order, in my experience.

P.S. My original take was that you wanted the most recent message sent *and* the most recent message received, for each sender and receiver. However, that's not what you asked for. I thought I'd leave this in for posterity since it could also be a useful answer to someone:

```
WITH Priorities AS (
   SELECT
      SNum = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Sender_id ORDER BY Message_id DESC),
      PNum = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Receiver_id ORDER BY Message_id DESC),
      *
   FROM
      Message
   WHERE
      '101' IN (Sender_id, Receiver_id)
)
SELECT *
FROM Priorities
WHERE 1 IN (SNum, PNum)
;
```

Comment: . . Another situation where I fully understand the answer, but not the upvotes.  Note that MessageId 1 is *not* in the desired output.  Your method would duplicate users, by having one row for the other user as sender and another row as receiver.

Comment: That's why I edited my answer to say that it wasn't answering the question, but an updated answer was coming along shortly! Does the new query satisfy?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't Erik.

Comment: @BenisonSam Sorry about that, try this now (I added a fiddle).

Comment: I also made a small tweak that makes the query more beautiful and removes an annoying condition--not sure if you saw that.

Comment: What type of query is this...?? Looks fine, working great. And is definitely a better solution. Can you please say what exactly are you doing in this query..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70881/discussion-between-benison-sam-and-erike).

Answer (score 3):

If you want the most recent message to/from another user, calculate the recency (based on `message_id`) for the *other* user as both sender and receiver.  The trick is to partition using the *other* user as the partitioning key.

Then choose the first one in the outer query:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when sender_id = 101 then receiver_id else sender_id end)
                                order by message_id desc) as seqnum
      from message m
      where 101 in (sender_id, receiver_id)
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What if we consider the message id to be just unique number and not a ordered identity column...?

Comment: @BenisonSam . . . You need some way to determine the most recent.  You can put in whatever column is used for that purpose.  Your sample code and data seem to be using `message_id` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Message_id, Sender_id, Receiver_id, Message, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Sender_id, Receiver_id ORDER BY Message_id DESC) OBD FROM Message
WHERE Sender_id = 101 OR Receiver_id = 101) A WHERE A.OBD = 1
```

Comment: Considered that MessasgeID as increamenting and alwasy the highest messageID is the latest.